# Problems with the example of solve_ivp [scipy.integrate]

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I am studying python for what concerns ode numerical integration, in particular I found the scipy.integrate function `solve_ipv` . I tried the example shown in the [scipy.integrate.solve_ipv page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) but there could be a **mistake in the code** related to the Lotka Volterra example:

```
def lotkavolterra(t, z, a, b, c, d):
    x, y = z
    return [a*x - b*x*y, -c*y + d*x*y]

sol = solve_ivp(lotkavolterra, [0, 15], [10, 5], args=(1.5, 1, 3, 1))

t = np.linspace(0, 15, 300)
z = sol.sol(t)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(t, z.T)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.legend(['x', 'y'], shadow=True)
plt.title('Lotka-Volterra System')
plt.show()
```

1. `sol.sol(t)` has no meaning in this code. What should we write? Maybe a tuple `z = sol.t, sol.y` ?
2. It is also clear that `len(sol.y[0])=57` and `len(sol.y[1])=57` while `t` has 300 elements. For this reason coupling their values for a plot can be a problem.

In the page there is also a plot of what we would obtain if the code run.

I don't think it's important but I am using python3.

EDIT: I did not insert `dense_output=True` in `solv_ipv()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the solver call

```
sol = solve_ivp(lotkavolterra, [0, 15], [10, 5], args=(1.5, 1, 3, 1),
                dense_output=True)
```

the last option `dense_output=True` is responsible for adding the `sol` function to the solution "bunch" object. This function implements the method-specific piecewise polynomial interpolation that in the literature is called "dense output". Thus the next two lines make complete sense, as `z = sol.sol(t)` contains a sample for any point in `t`.

This option does not change the sequence of internal nodes and step sizes. `sol.t` and `sol.y` contain the same values with or without that option. There is even no additional computation involved, as the stepper computes this interpolation polynomial for every step. This is used even without the dense output option in the event mechanism. Only the memory use is increased when the individual interpolation polynomials are stored after each step and assembled in the dense output function.

---

To avoid the confusion of `sol.sol`, some have taken `res` for "result" or similar as the variable name for the solver return value, so that the interpolation function is accessed as `res.sol(t)`.

Comment: Yes I forgot that call but in my code I didn't use `dense_output=True`. Briefly speaking does this command make the output array smoother in relation to the parameter `t`? Are we definitely changing the real vector output?

Comment: Yes, a polynomial interpolation makes a smoother look than a piecewise linear function. Matlab's ode45 etc. does this better with the "Refine" option that adds internal points of the segment of each step to the output. So a plot looks more smooth but the density of the points is still adapted to the actual "curvature" of the solution.